# using getopt_long, how to store two values in optarg?

Tags: c, linux, getopt-long

If I define

```
static struct option long_option[]={ {"add", 1, 0, 'a'} }
```

can I store two values in the optarg? This is the code what I want to use:

```
./a.out --add Tommy 123-123-123
```

and I would like to store two values, Tommy and 123-123-123 by using --add once.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't. According to getopt man page, getopt uses next argument. So you can :

- either use `./a.out --add 'Tommy 123-123-123'` and the quotes makes the shell take `'Tommy 123-123-123'` as a single argument
- or program by hand your own option parser